# JavaMail: MessagingException: Got bad greeting from SMTP host — Error Code 250

Tags: java, sockets, email, jakarta-mail

**Requirements**:
- Only 1 connection to mail server allowed (restriction from my customer)
- **Don't close connection** after sending a mail, resend mails over existing connection (better performance as transport.connect() is not needed for each mail)
- Send all mails over that connection
- If connection fails, reconnect, send mail
- Java 1.6

My code works well, but sometimes I get the `javax.mail.MessagingException` with error code `250: Got bad greeting from SMTP host`.
The **nested exception** is `java.net.SocketException: Socket closed`:

Here is my client code, the line is marked, where the exception is thrown:

```
// the mail service is a singleton and has one property to store the transport
// object that gets initialized when the singleton instance gets created:
private Transport transport = null;

// props, authU, authP and msg are all passed as a parameter to the sending method:
if (transport == null) {
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
}
if(!transport.isConnected()) {
    transport.connect(authU, authP); // <<<<< This line throws the exception !
}
transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
```

Obviously `transport.isConnected()` detects no connection, but the connection() does not reopen or recreate a socket. My assumption was that it would do all the necessary stuff for me.

Is there a proper client solution to make sure that exception does not get thrown?
A workaround would be to catch the exception and resend the mail, but I don't like workarounds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe as a workaround is actually the right way to do it.

There's nothing preventing the server from dropping the connection between the time you call the isConnected method and the time you call the sendMessage method, so in the worst case you always have to be prepared to handle the exception.

Comment: catching the exception around `connect()` is now my current implementation. I still wonder whether this is really the most elegant solution?

Comment: We can argue about "elegant", but there's nothing you can do to prevent a network or server failure that would cause the connect or sendMessage methods from throwing an exception when that failure occurs.

Comment: I still have an issue where an exception is thrown at `transport.sendMessage()` right after I reconnected via `transport.connect()`.  Is it required to re-initialize the **Session** object too?

Comment: No, you don't need to reinitialize the Session.  The Session just stores configuration information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :

```
public static void mail(Reporter report) {
    
 
        if(!sendEmail.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
            return;
        }
        
 
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
 
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });
 
        try {     
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from-email@gmail.com"));
            if(!bccEmail.trim().isEmpty()){
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(bccEmail));
            }
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(toEmail));
            message.setSubject(" Testing ");
            message.setText("automatic email  ,"+report);
            Transport.send(message);
 
            System.out.println("Email Done");
 
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the short version of your answer is: try out the static method `Transport.send()` ?

Comment: When looking at the source code of `Transport.send()` I see that it calls `transport.close()` after sending the message. This causes a dramatic performance decrease if you have to send out many mails (1000 and more). I need a solution where `transport.close()` does not get called and reuses existing connections of the transport layer. **See my requirements**.